# What if I create a simple controller in Groovy & Grails and use it as Rest API Controller, other then extending RestFulController?

Tags: rest, api, grails

I am using Groovy & Grails , and I wanted the difference between using nomal Grails controller as Rest Controller the using RestFulController class.And secondly I wanted to know which API implementation (Jersey or RestEasy) is Grails using at it's end.

Comment: The difference between extending `grails.rest.RestfulController` and writing your own is that, well, you have to write it all yourself.

Comment: This question is a little like asking "what is the difference between your car and my car", but I don't get to know anything about your car.  There is no way to answer the question in a helpful way.

Comment: You are only required to comment when you know the answer.

Comment: @John "You are only required to comment when you know the answer" - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted the difference between using nomal Grails controller as Rest
>   Controller the using RestFulController class.

The difference would depend what you put in your normal Grails controller.  If you put the same behavior in your normal controller as is provided by `RestfulController`, then of course there would be no functional difference.  If you did not put the same behavior in your normal controller as is provided by `RestfulController`, then the details of what you put in your controller will dictate the differences between it and `RestfulController`.

`RestfulController` provides basic CRUD capability and a number of methods designed for extension to customize that behavior.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v3.3.9/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/RestfulController.groovy.

> And secondly I wanted to know which API implementation (Jersey or
>   RestEasy) is Grails using at it's end.

Grails is not using Jersey or RestEasy.  Grails implements its own API.

Comment: RestfullController provides different methods , so I was asking for the use case of any of them.

Comment: " I was asking for the use case of any of them" - That isn't how the original question reads.  There are different use cases for the different methods/actions.  For example, the `index` action sends a query to the database to retrieve a `List` of instances and writes them to the response.  The `delete` action deletes an instance from the database.  Each of the actions does something different.